# DockPanel Children auto Width

Tags: wpf, dockpanel

I have this Dockpanel:

```
<DockPanel x:Name="sp_colJournees" Margin="10,110,10,10" Dock="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

And I try to add some children:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    var a = new ColJournee(DateTimeConvert.IntToDay((int) _debutCalendar.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek), _debutCalendar.AddDays(i).ToShortDateString());
    sp_colJournees.Children.Add(a);
}
```

Output:

[image]

But I want 7 children with same width.

Comment: You can probably use UniformGrid with 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ProportionalPanel for this. [Here](http://www.alecbryte.com/post/2009/01/16/WPF-Proportional-Panel.aspx) is an implementation of a proportional panel.